# Sort by number of Customers Jira

Tags: jira

We currently have a Jira instance and I have had another odd request to sort the posts by the number of customers affected. Is this at all possible or will this require some custom work on my part?

Comment: How do you keep track how many customers are affected.  Is it a custom field ?

Comment: we have a field - company name in our jira issue, the companies are added to this. But the request is to sort by the number of companies in this field. For instance a,b,c we would want the count to be 3 and then when we sort its sorted by the number of companies... Sorry if my question was unclear at all.

Comment: I think I'd create a custom Calculated field that shows the number of entries and supports being sorted on in the Issue Navigator. Or add javascript to the field description to display the count instead of the values and then export the results to Excel and sort there.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to add a customer impact number to your configuration (a custom field of type number) and bump it each time a new customer is added to the company name field.

You might even add a simple javascript which automatically sets the field if the company name field is modified ...